# How to show rg's search result in a new buffer?

Tags: emacs

I used rg tool to do code search in emacs, but it always show result in a split window, my question is how to show search result in a new buffer?

Comment: Do you mean "in a new frame"? I'm pretty sure it would put the results in a new buffer: the question is how should the buffer be displayed? Note that emacs calls "frames" what desktop environments usually call "windows".

Comment: I.e. a buffer contains text (and may or may not be displayed anywhere!).  A window displays a single buffer (which buffer that is may change over time).  A frame displays one or more windows, depending on whether / how its window configuration has been split.

Comment: how to put the results in a new buffer? thanks

Comment: That's the same question, which remains unclear.  Your complaint is that "it always show result in a split window" which has nothing at all to do with whether or not a new buffer was used.  Please clarify your question.  Whether it's a new or an old buffer has no relevance to how/where it gets displayed.

Comment: Many emacs users are not familiar with the meaning of the words frame/window/buffer. I would translate it into: "The `rg` tool always show the result in (a new buffer in) a split window. How to show the search result in (a new buffer in) a new separate frame?"

Answer (score 0):

You could give [deadgrep](https://github.com/Wilfred/deadgrep) a try. It put each search result in a new buffer.